# Matrix Date Field Problem

Tags: matrix

I set up a brand new EE install of v2.8.1 along with the latest and greatest Matrix v2.5.10.

I added a Date Column Type to my matrix field and when I go to edit or publish an entry, when clicking the date column, the date picker defaults to Dec 1969. I assume something is broken somewhere but I have no idea where to begin to look.

Any ideas?

Also, is there a tag that can be used in my template that will simply output the last modified date of any matrix row so I don't have to use the date field at all?

Please advise.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: I have this problem as well. I've just added a date field to a Matrix on an EE 2.7.3 site with Matrix 2.5.10. When you go to select a date in the Publish section, the calendar defaults to Dec 1969, not a recent date. You need to choose a date and then edit the text to the date needed. I would also like a tag that would output the last modified date of any matrix row so I don't need to use the date field too (which is why I added added the date field to start with). I'll post this on Twitter to see if anyone can help.

Comment: We'll look into this and get back to you. FFR, please submit bug reports to support@pixelandtonic.com – thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering if it's somehow linked to the server the site is on? I copied files out of a Mountee folder onto my desktop yesterday and they're also dated 31st December 1969. Unfortunately I know nothing about servers or why this would happen. Hopefully someone from Twitter can help.

Comment: I definitely think this may be something to do with the server. When I create a new entry, the calendar defaults to today's date. It's only when I go to add a date to an entry created prior to adding the calendar field to the matrix, then I get the December 1969 calendar. Is the calendar reading the file creation date, which may have been corrupted in some way on the server?

Comment: I just checked the entry creation dates on the Dates tab for the older entries and they are correct, earlier this month. So the database holds the correct date.